# Is there a way for await to return Result<T, E> and not T?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await

I am using reqwest to make a get request on an API using the function:

```
async fn get_item_response(client: &Client, id: &str) -> Result<Response, reqwest::Error> {
    let base = "http://someurl.com/item?={item_id}"
    .replace("{item_id}", id);
    client.get(&base).send()
}
```

```
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let response = get_item_response(&client, "1").await?;
}
```

The response is a Response type and not a Result which means I can't check if an error occured without panicking.
Is there a way to access the Result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `?` is not an integral part of `await`. It is an operator itself, which will unwrap valid values or return erroneous values, propagating them to the calling function. Without it, you then have to check the result yourself:

```rust
match get_item_response(&client, "1").await {
    Ok(response) => /* do things with response */,
    Err(e) => /* deal with error */,
}
```